# Firebase Auth does not work in TWA but works in PWA

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps, google-signin, trusted-web-activity

firebase `auth` of PWA version of app

https://app.managemyrides.com

works perfectly and I get the user in `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange callback`,
but when tried same TWA version of the app, `auth` always fails to login.

**TWA version :**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.managemyrides

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same.

Comment: No.. Still stuck with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am answering my own question,

The problem was there with the firebase.

I upgraded the version to 5.7.0 from 6.x.x and the above-mentioned problem disappeared.